# Is there a Mersenne prime that is also a primorial prime?

Tags: number-theory

Could someone point out a Mersenne prime that is also a primorial prime? are there more than one such Mersenne primes? is there a OEIS sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it certainly can’t be one less than a product of multiple primes as that would imply that $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots = 2^n$ which is false because they have different prime factors. However 3, 7, and 31 are each primordial and Mersenne so there you go.